# UI5 Odata call with odata.v2 throws an error

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am new to SAP UI5 and oDATA. I have created a ODATA Service and it is been called in onInit function of an UI5 App.

If I use `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` then I am able to see the data from the backend table but if I call same oDATA service using `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` then I am getting below error message

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'V', "Validierun"... is not valid JSON sap.ui.model.odata.ODataMessageParser`

[image: Error message]

Comment: Okay it seems that the response of the OData service may be corrupt. Can you check in the network tab of the developer tools, what data has been received?

Comment: it is resolved. I am using oDATA service with http link instead of https. Thank you